# Why code still run to the end of recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I thought the following code will never reach to the `console.log` lines, because the `next()` function already run before to reach to the `console.log` lines and the `if else` condition with `return` prevent it too, but it is not so. Why?

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var i = 0;
function next() {
    if (i < arr.length) {
        next(i++);
        console.log('why go here 1:' + i); // 3,3,3
    } else {
        return;
    }
    console.log('why go here 2:' + i); // 3,3,3
}
next();
```

Comment: I don't understand yor question. Are you asking why the console only shows `3`? or why is it showing anything at all?

Comment: You can't skip an `if` from within itself. If the condition `i < arr.length` is met, both instructions `next(i++)` and `console.log(...)` will be executed regardless of the result of the first instruction.

Comment: for me it is very important acknowledge, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of those calls to `next()` will return once the edge condition is met (in this case once `i` is larger than `arr.length`). This is the part of recursion that's usually called "unwinding" — each recursive call returns as the calls it called return. So once the `next()` function returns it continues on to the `console.log()`

You can adjust your code so it logs when the function starts and returns with a count to visualize the recursion:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let i = 0;
let space =  1
function next() {
    let s = space++
    console.log(" ".repeat(s) + `next ${s} called`)
    if (i < arr.length) {
        next(i++);
    } else {
        console.log("edge condition -- finally start unwinding")
        console.log(" ".repeat(s) + `next ${s} retured from edge condition`)
        return;
    }
    console.log(" ".repeat(s) + `next ${s} retured`)
}
next();
```

Here you can see the four `next()` functions called without returning, but once you hit the edge condition, they unwind and return in the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to step through it with a debugger or pen/paper to understand the flow completely.

When `next(i++)` returns, like after any function call, it will go to the next line.  If you want the code to stop, you have to `return` after calling `next(i++)`.  Ex: `return next(i++);` or `next(i++); return;`

Comment: "When next(i++) returns, like after any function call, it will go to the next line." I thought after the function returns, nothing happens to the next line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement/function  will run everything in the scope unless there's something such as a `break` to terminate the current loop, switch, or label statement.